# Full Calendar : On click date I want to highlight whole week of selected date by changing its background

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

What I want is Whenever I click the date in Month view it should highlight the whole week by changing its background (like in google small view calendar which is displayed at the left corner side).

[image]

For Example: 
If I click the date 3(Septemeber), it would change the BACKGROUND COLOR of WHOLE WEEK from the date 2 to 8(whole row) and when I click any of the date of next week/previous week it would change the background color of that entered date's week.

How can I select the whole week in month view by changing its background color -  http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `dayClick` callback. Check this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/sStbC/

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Actually, I have performed this functionality according to my needs like google calendar . [http://jsfiddle.net/bAhmed/pD4EC/7/] **Now I want you functionality to be done in small calendar view of mentioned example** My code is doing some cases like **1.**When you once click on any of the date in SMALL CALENDAR view it would change the view in BIG CALENDAR and show the date.       **2** When you click on the same date in SMALL CALENDAR view it would show the Monthview in BIG CALENDAR and then it would show the month view unless you double click any of the date. _**ON this case I need help**_